# Aptitude on Debian 6.0.4 "media change" to CD ROM

Tags: debian, apt

I've just installed Debian 6.0.4 on VirtualBox, and I'm trying to install g++. So, into the terminal I typed:

```
aptitude install build-essential
```

But it's trying to get the package from disk:

```
Media Change: Please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20120128-12:53' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter].
```

Why isn't it just downloading it from Debian's repositories? Can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comment the line in /etc/apt/sources.list that points to CD, that is add a '#' character at the beginning of the line, so that it looks similar to:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20120128-12:53]/ squeeze main
```